# Cannot generate Zomato Api key

Tags: android, api, zomato-api

I am trying to integrate **Zomato api** in my application.I have gone through their official doc,but I am not able to find the way to generate zomato api key.

Please see [this](https://www.zomato.com/api/documentation#) link.

The doc says:

*API Authentication*

*API key*

*In order to use the API you must obtain an API key from Zomato. This key is unique to each user/developer. Please keep the key confidential as any misuse might result in termination of access of the key to the API.*

*For authenticating requests in real time*

*Your API key must be passed as the X-Zomato-API-Key header in every request.*

But I cannot find a way to create the API key.Anyone knows how to create one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just registered via my google account, Zomato said this

[image]

Here is the link
https://www.zomato.com/api

Comment: Is there any way to get API key from Zomato